# vkCreateImageView results in an access violation even though it returns VK_SUCCESS

Tags: c++, vulkan

I've been following this tutorial https://vulkan-tutorial.com/ to try and make a minecraft clone to learn how vulkan works. However, trying to create an ImageView results in "Access violation reading location 0x00000000000000F8" as can be seen here:

[image: Access violation message]

And here you can see that the vkCreateImageView function returns VK_SUCCESS

[image: vkCreateImageView returns VK_SUCCESS]

Initially I thought that the validation layer might be causing the exception, but removing the validation error leads to a "vector subscript out of range" error once the FrameBuffer creation tries to access the created ImageViews.

I have tried several things including: Having the VkImageView as a function variable and allocating it manually but they all result in the same Access Violation at 0x..F8. Compiling it in x86 just results in the Access Violation address changing to 0x000000A8.

I'm using the Vulkan SDK 1.0.65.1.

Comment: Does it work with layers off? ;; Is your `&swapchainImageViews[i]` properly allocated?

Comment: Yeah it works, they are allocated once the swapChainImageViews vector is resized. I looked at the tutorial's FAQ again just to be sure and noticed that there may be validation errors if MSI Afterburner is running. Turning MSI afterburner off fixed the Access Violation exception.

Answer (score 1):

The Access Violation was being caused by MSI Afterburner / RivaTuner, stopping them makes the validation layers work properly again.

Source: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/FAQ